# How to exclude rows by count in R

Tags: r

I want to exclude participants that have less than 40% "Y" answers in the graph.
[image: I want to exclude participants that have less than 40% "Y" answers in the graph].

I've tried filtering it out with the dplyr package, but there is something I'm missing.

```
exp2.Hacc <- subset(exp2, !is.na(ExpecSg))
exp2.Hacc <- exp2.Hacc %>% 
  group_by(Participant,ExpecSg) %>% 
  summarise(count=n()) %>% 
  filter(count=n(Y) => 0.4)
```

The first part of my code shows me I'm on the right track

```
# A tibble: 46 x 3
# Groups:   Participant [?]
   Participant ExpecSg count
   <fct>       <fct>   <int>
 1 AA          N           5
 2 AA          Y          19
 3 AB          N          14
 4 AB          Y          14
 5 AC          N           6
 6 AC          Y          20
 7 AD          N          15
 8 AD          Y          11
 9 AE          N           5
10 AE          Y          24
# ... with 36 more rows
```

However, the filtering gives me an error:

```
Error: `count` (`count = n(Y) > 0.4`) must not be named, do you need `==`?
```

I understand that there's something I'm missing, but I cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: first, calculate the ratio then filter.

Comment: So your tibble needs an extra column with the ratios and then you can subset according to the values in this column.

Comment: Could you please copy the text of that first chunk of code so that it can be reproduced/indexed?